# Python names/bindings - why aren't all lists of the same length the "same list"?

Tags: python, pointers

I know there are tons of resources out there about pointers and references (or rather: names, and bindings!) in Python, but I am struggling to understand one last point:

I get that if `a = 1` and if `b = 1` than they both are 'bound' to the same exact 1 and will have the same `id()` (and therefore, I think memory address). I also get that if you set:

```
a = [1, 2, 4]
b = a
b[0] = 45
# a is now [45, 2, 4]
```

because `a` and `b` are bound to the same list (object), and changes in one result in changes to another. Similarly, `a[0]` and `b[0]` are the same object. The list contains other objects with different ids - aka list identity is not bound to its contents.

Okay. So far so good. I can accept that there are 'unborn' lists and numbers floating around waiting to initialized (only once though!), and that Python takes care of assigning a memory space for them once we want them. Why then, if I do:

```
d = [1, 2]
e = [145, 7]
# id(d) and id(e) are not the same?!
```

Shouldn't there only be a single 2-element list in Python's existence? This would be consistent to me (and then there is only a single 1, a single 2, a single 145...etc).

Any explanation would appreciated - and that includes ones that relate it back to pointers (since I am also somewhat mystified about the decisions that are made at a memory management level, but I suppose that's the concern of Python's execution model and not me!)

Comment: Euhh...Because they **contain different elements**? Say they were the same object, what would you return for `d[0]`? `1` or `145`?

Comment: Seems like an odd question, kind of like: Why should there be more that one 2-child family in existence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are being misled by an optimization present in CPython for `int`s, namely, int-caching. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers) famous question. This is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong):

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all
>   integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you
>   actually just get back a reference to the existing object.

In almost every other instance, using a literal creates a *new object*. Indeed, use `int`s outside that range, and you'll see the normal behavior:

```
>>> a = 100000
>>> b = 100000
>>> id(a)
4322630608
>>> id(b)
4322630640
>>> c = a
>>> id(a) == id(b)
False
>>> id(a) == id(c)
True
```

And I need to repeat this almost every single day, but *assignment in Python **never** copies*.

Comment: But if I read the question correctly, the OP is not asking about `int`s, but about lists, which makes the question more, well, *weird*.

Comment: Amazing - thank you so much. I would have never found that question on my own. I was trying hard to nod my head and be like "this is reasonable, this makes sense, there's only one of everything!" Thank goodness that's not how Python actually works

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem True, but his intuitions are being colored by a weird exception to the general rule regarding literals.

Comment: @HFBrowning please please please read this: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html and make sure you understand it.

Comment: Thanks for the link @juanpa.arrivillaga, I will. This model is super different than R (where everything is copied) so I appreciate any new-to-me reference

Comment: @HFBrowning well, for what it's worth, I'd say Python is a *much* more elegant language than R. R is great for learning statistics in a classroom, but my experience is that it is a terrible language to get anything substantive done. And may the gods of OOP help you if you want to understand the three different class/object systems that coexist at the same time! That being said, it can be very handy for quick-and-dirty data analysis tasks, data exploration, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`=` is an assignment.

`[1, 2, 3]` and `10` are objects.

if you write `10` or `[1, 2, 3]` python creates an objects. if you don't use an assignment, garbage collector will remove it. but if you do, python will assign a pointer to the newly created object to a given name/variable, ie:

```
a = [1, 2]
```

next, when you assign a variable to another variable, python will copy a pointer from the first variable, ie:

```
b = a
```

`b` now contains pointer to the same object as `a`. but any newly created object, even if the content is the same, is a different object. so:

```
id(a) != id([1, 2])
```

now, depending on implementation (so it can change at any time and you should not depend on it) there might be a "shortcut" for speed efficiency, and objects representing some common values might be created by default. and that's why on some implementations `id(1) == id(1)`, but what's confusing `id(5555) != id(5555)`.